# How to translate Matplotlib to pyQt5

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on pyqt5 and I have to use some matplotlib I looked on how to embeed the matplotlib in pyqt5 using matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg but I still have couple of line that I couldn't set them to work for pyqt5
I mean I still don't know how to show this on my canvas ?

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, 
etc.)."""

def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

    #self.compute_initial_figure(self,img)

    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
    self.setParent(parent)

    FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

def compute_initial_figure(self,img):
    pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

 def compute_initial_figure(self,img):

        pattern,code,label = self.freeman(img) #iam getting this from another function 
        na = plt.imshow(label,cmap='Greys')
        plt.plot([i[1] for i in pattern],[i[0] for i in pattern ])
        plt.show()
        #t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        #s = sin(2*pi*t)
        #self.axes.plot(t,s)
```

and inside my MainWindow I am just using a normal class instance :

```
        self.sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.tab_2, width=2, height=2, 
                  dpi=100)
        self.sc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 320, 300, 300))
```

Comment: I recommend that you remove one of your tags and add the `Matplotlib` tag instead. You will get more help that way.

Comment: Which pyqt are you using? One version tag would be better. A lot of stuff has changed between 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code isn't reproducible but this is a version that works with `PyQt5`. What certainly wouldn't work in your code -- I think -- is calling `plt.show()`. You want to plot with the figure object generated with `MyMplCanvas`, and I think `pyplot` will use its own UI instead of that

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 
import sys
import numpy as np

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5.4, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        dat = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (20, 2))
        self.axes.scatter(dat[:, 0], dat[:, 1])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas()

        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```